# WIX - MSI: How to check highest version of jre 1.7 - till 1.6 from multiple version of JRE (1,8, 1.7.0_80, 1.7.0_79 and 1.6.0_45) in the system

Tags: java, wix, windows-installer

How can I check highest version of 1.7 JRE installed in the system by using WIX? 
1) My application works for only 1.6 or 1.7 of JRE's. 
2) So during MSI installation need to find our highest version of 1.7 or 1.6.
  a) If in the system it has installed 1.8.0_45, 1.7.0_80, 1.7.0_79 and 1.6.0_45. In this case I have to find out the 1.7.0_80 and need to get the installed path.

As I know below way we can find out the highest version of the JAVA installed in the system.

```
 <Property Id="JRE_64">
        <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_64R" Root="HKLM"    Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="CurrentVersion"    Type="raw" Win64="yes"  />
  </Property>
```

Based on this value checking is it 1.8 of JAVA, then need to get 1.7

```
<?if [JRE_64] < 1.6 AND  [JRE_64] >= 1.8 ?> 
        <Property Id="JRE_64_7">
            <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_64R_7" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="Java7FamilyVersion" Type="raw" Win64="yes"  />
        </Property> 
        <?if ([JRE_64_7]  >= 1.7  AND  [JRE_64_7] < 1.8) ?>
            <Property Id="JRE_64_6">
                <RegistrySearch Id="JRE_64R_6" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment" Name="Java6FamilyVersion" Type="raw" Win64="yes"  />
            </Property> 
        <?endif?>
    <?endif?>
```

But this **if condition is not working for Property value comparison**? How can I solve it? any suggestion please.

Answer (score 1):

try custom action, include a vbs binary try to use wmi object and fetch the properties of Java family

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")

Set allProds= objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT Name,Vendor,Version FROM Win32_Product")
```

Iterate through the allProds, if name is java check for version

> Sample Response
>
> Version=6.0.100
>
> Vendor=Sun Microsystems, Inc.
>
> Name=Java(TM) 6 Update 10